# CSS column-count: 2 ignored until I use 3 items

Tags: css, column-count

I'm using column-count: 2 to split NAV element into 2 columns. In first demo I have 3 buttons and they are correctly split into two columns, but when I use only 2 buttons, they are not split to two columns. They should be side by side but they are under each other. How to make them side by side?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  background-color: navy;
  width: 200px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<nav><button>First</button><button>Second</button><button>Third</button></nav>

<hr>

<nav><button>First</button><button>Second</button></nav>
```

Edit: they are correctly side by side in firefox but not in chrome

Comment: They seem to be side by side already, no ?

Comment: Only in firefox, not in chrome

Comment: It's working in Safari as well, cause I'm using Safari.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue:

button {
display: block;
}